# JS file loading multiple times while showing popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html page naming "Compose.html". In that html page, i am loading js file naming "Compose.js".

I am having another main page naming "Main.html".

In the Main.html, i am loading this "Compose.html" as popup div.

I want to show this popup two times simultaneously side by side, so i am loading this "Compose.html" two times in a popup div.

Now my "Compose.js" is also loading two times.

So my click events are happening twice.

How to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show relevent code plzz???

Comment: try this, load ur compose.js in main.html

Comment: are u loading compose.html using iFrame??